# Does my GPU finally needs thermal compound?

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, gpu, cooling, temperature

I have the following PC configuration and since September 2011 when I bought and assembled it the only maintenance I did was cleaning every fans with compressed air.

```
SSD: Crucial RealSSD M4 128GB 2.5" Read 415MB/s Write 175MB/s Sata3 CT128M4SSD2
HDD: Samsung Spinpoint F3 1TB 3.5" 7200rpm 32MB SATA2 HD103SJ
Mobo: Asrock Z68 EXTREME4 Socket 1155 Intel Z68 DDR3 SATA3 USB3 HDMI ATX
RAM: DDR3 Corsair Vengeance CMZ8GX3M2A1600C8 1600MHz 8GB (2x4GB) CL8
CPU: Intel Core i7-2600K 3.40GHz Socket 1155 95W - GPU Sandy Bridge Boxed BX80623I72600K
Power Adapter: Corsair Professional Series Gold AX750 750W 80Plus Gold High Performance
CPU Sink: Noctua NH-D14 socket 775/1156/1366/AM2/AM2+/AM3 140mm
GPU: VGA MSI N580GTX Twin Frozr II/OC GeForce GTX 580 Core 823MHz Memory GDDR5 4276MHz 1536MB 2xDVI HDMI
```

Now we come to the part I care the most. I have monitored my GPU temperatures lastly, especially during playing a new game ([requirements here](https://support.wildstar-online.com/entries/31187868-System-Requirements)) when the two fans under it start running very fast, something never happened to me before.

The idle temperatures for my CPU are around **35-40 C**, while during the game are around **50-55 C**. For the GPU, idle temperature resides around **50-60 C**, and during the game hit up to **80-85 C**. My GPU is not under/overclocked, I never touched MSI Afterburner because I don't know well how it works and never needed it.

I know I should not be scared because the maximum declared temperature for the GTX 580 from Nvidia is 97 C, but still I think that looking at the requirements of games like the one linked above, it shouldn't reach this temperature and the fans shouldn't start spinning and causing noise like this.

I use dual monitor with different frequency (120 Hz main monitor in DVI, 60 Hz secondary monitor in VGA adapted from DVI)

Now comes the real question: A friend of mine at work suggested me to change the **stock** thermal compound on the processor of my GPU since I never did it. Do you suggest me to do the same? Have you got any suggestion to achieve this without causing troubles? Right in this moment, I got in my hands an **ARCTIC MX-2 (4g) Non-Electricity Conductive, Non-Capacitive and Carbon-Based Thermal Compound**.

Comment: It may be better to explain what you want to change it from and to.

Comment: I updated the question with some informations about the new thermal compound I would like to use on the gpu processor

Comment: I also added some other informations that could be important

Comment: Depends on your level of skill with this sort of customisation. A new 3rd party cooler can be a massive advantage over stock as well as a better 3rd party thermal paste. However get it wrong and you could buying a new Graphics Card so be careful. I think the noise and the temp sounds about right for a modern card when gaming myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPU and CPU fans can run faster on high load.
New BIOSes have such functions (e.g. Smart Fan Control) which increase fan RPM when CPU/GPU gets hot, and decrease RPM when it gets cold. So there is nothing strange if your fans run faster.

If you think your game can't do it, probably you've got malware with BitCoin miner.
Scan you computer for viruses. If the game is not original version, then it may have malware, remove it.

To reduce fan speed and noise, first of all dust all fans.
New thermal paste fill decrease temperature and reduce fan noise too and is always good. But if temperature isn't near to critical, there's no need to buy it.
Do a [GPU Stress Test](https://www.google.com/search?q=GPU%20Stress%20Test) (with tools like [AIDA64](http://www.aida64.com/)), if it gets near to critical value (in your case ~90 C), then buy thermal paste.

Comment: @Wired I see your game is [WildStar](http://www.wildstar-online.com/en/) and it's [recomended settings](https://support.wildstar-online.com/entries/31187868-System-Requirements) are near to your hardware. So it can cause high load (no malware) and can increase fan speed.

Comment: Taking a look at the recomended settings I see that the required GPU is quite lower than mine, this is why I find it strange that it's requiring so much efforts to run. Could it also be a matter of RAM? Also, what program do I require to specifically scan for BitCoin miners? Actually going on the "stock" Windows 8 Defender.

Comment: Any good antivirus (such as Kaspersky Internet Security, Norton IS, Bitdefender) will do the work. But I think there's no bitcoin miner in your PC. GTX 580 is not so far from their recomended GTX 460, especially if you run the game on maximum settings. So the game itself can use a lot GPU (without malware). And no, RAM can't make GPU fans go faster.

Comment: The thing is that they starts running even when I set everything to low, this is so strange

Comment: Clean fans and tell us what happens

Comment: As stated in the main topic I already did this in the very beginning

Answer (score -1):

The forum has answered the majority of what i was going to say
my only comment left is

Don't replace the Stock Thermal Compound

if it has Thermal Compound Leave it there

Also, if your asking the question, it therefore proves that you don't have the experience to replace Thermal Compound, and incidentally, if your freind tells you "just do it.it's easy"

it then proves he doesn't have the skill to do it either
i see this a lot

Trust me, There's not reason for you to remove it, the manufacturer applied it and used the appropriate one for that hardware, Leave it there

Sounds like it would hurt to upgrade your PC either

Keep your fans clean, blow the dust out of your Power Supply and from your Motherboard
Further to all this Dust Maintenance

You need to have sufficient hardware before Optimizing Software or looking at cooling Technologies

I hope all this helps

Comment: thanks for your answer but I have been reading in many places that a third party thermal compound could actually help. I have much skill on the software side but I know how a computer is made of, I know how to assemble it and so on.. If I will need to learn it and its necessary, I will be able to do it carefully

Comment: Your Right, it could, But it depends, When your talking about Thermal Compoound you need to get a good so that it effectively Transfers the heat the Heatsink, and you have to apply it properly otherwise it may not be very effective, it's not straight forward,  but, given the right conditions and you do it correctly, it could help, sure

Comment: "Don't replace the Stock Thermal Compound" is very wrong. Stock thermal compund can't last forever. I think one must change thermal compound once in about 5 years.

Comment: Martin, No one can have skill without trying ;) @Wired in case you want to change it, just do google/youtube and do carefully.

Comment: @ Jet, Mate i agree, Assumming that the person has absolutely no probelms if they fry the CPU, or any other piece of hardware or if they have not problems accidentally getting minor burns,  then , sure.. go ahead and try and see what happens,   when i was 13, i fixed a starter motor, i didn't know it was a starter motor, i just new it was some sort of motor that needed electricity to work,  so you know what i did,   i took your advice,   i took those 2 contacts (those 2 big Copper Wires) , got a pair of rubber kitchen gloves, and i stuck it in the Mains Power

Comment: Did i Learn by Trying... Yes i did, what did i learn,... that i could have killed myself, and thank god that it occured to me , at such a young age, to put on rubber gloves.   People have to try, i agree,  Practical is important,  but, when it's controlled and safe.  you don't do that stuff on things that cost huge amounts of money that you can't replace, or when it's dangerous.  do you agree ?,  because if he takes your advise and ignores me, and he stuffs up the thermal compund thing,  are you going to take responsiblity for the advise given... are you ?

Comment: @Martin If the thermal compund has gone dry or old, then you definately should change it. To compare trying this fairly easy and common operation with a dangerous thing like holding copper wires to a motor in your hands is way out of proportion. Modern compunds do not have any electric conductive material in them like the old silver ones, so even if you manage to get some on the circuits nect to the GPU you can easily wipe it off with a cotton swab and some alcohol. (Which you should use for cleaning off the old compund anyway) Worst case, you manage to break your graphics card, sure, but this